# Why won't my viewer display the results of the method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

happy is a integer variable that I have set as either 0 or 1. If it's 0 I want to display "No" and if it's 1 I want to display "Yes"

In my controller I have:

```
helper_method :happy_to_text
def happy_to_text(happy)
  happy > 0 ? 'Yes' : 'No'
end

def edit
  @todo_item = @todo_list.todo_items.find(params[:id])
end
```

If I try:

```
<td><%= happy_to_text(1) %></td>
```

it works correctly, displaying "Yes"

If I try:

```
<td><%= todo_item.happy %></td>
```

it works correctly, displaying "1"

If I try:

```
<td><%= happy_to_text(@todo_item.happy) %></td>
```

It fails with the error:

```
"undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass"
```

I'm sure I'm missing something basic, but I'm stuck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `todo_item.happy` is `nil`.  Can you make sure it has a numeric value as per your method expectation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object `todo_item` is `nil` because no value has been assigned to it.  It appears that you're attempting to use it in an ERB view, which probably means that it's intended to come from the database.

You should have a statement in your controller action (the one for the view) that does something like this:

```
def show
  @todo_item = TodoItem.find(params[:id])
end
```

It's possible that in your view code, you're just missing the `@` prefix for the variable when you use it in your view.  In that case, you probably meant the code to look like this:

```
<td><%= happy_to_text(@todo_item.happy) %></td>
```

Otherwise, you're missing the code to assign a value to `todo_item`, and you'll need to do that before you can attempt to use the value.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. When I update it to
<td><%= happy_to_text(@todo_item.happy) %></td>

I get undefined method `happy' for nil:NilClass

I do have the following in my controller.

def edit
    @todo_item = @todo_list.todo_items.find(params[:id])
  end

Comment: @Chris That's good information, but won't be enough to go on to solve this issue.  You're not getting a value in the @todo_item variable, and it could be due to any one of a number of reasons: database values missing, improper model definition, etc.  The way that you retrieve the value (`@todo_item = @todo_list.todo_items.find(params[:id])`) is odd, but might be appropriate for your app.  Please post the models for TodoList and TodoItem, and the logs for the edit action.  You can click the `edit` link below your question (above the comments) to add this information to the question.

Comment: I'm not sure what I did differently, but it's working. Thanks for the help!